# Jquery how to trigger click on an element that gains focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, tizen-web-app, caph-framework

I am working with caph framework and i trying to click in every id focused

```
$(event.currentTarget).on('selected',function() {

    var value = $(this).prop('id');

    $('#' + $(this).prop('id')).trigger('click');

});
```

Comment: Edit to add tag for [CAPH framework](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/d34/index) and clarify question title.

Comment: The question body says "every id focused" but the `select` event is generated by selecting text in a text box or text area. Please edit the question to explain what you are trying to do in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the event target with $(this) in jQuery. To automatically click on the selected element you could do

```
$(event.currentTarget).on('select', function() {
     $(this).click()
     // or $(this).trigger('click')
};
```

If I understand your question right though you're asking how to click *every* element with a given ID - please note that you should be using classes for this, as IDs are supposed to be unique. You could achieve that with the following:

```
$(event.currentTarget).on('select', function() {
     $('.yourClassName').click()
};
```

This will click on every element with the given class.